# BAM looping of multiple xml's from an BizTalk Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-bam

I have a BizTalk Orchestration which loops to create multiple XML files. I have configured BAM activities and views and deployed the Tracking .btt file to track the data.

The BAM activity does not loop through these multiple XML files, it creates only one instance. I need the BAM activity to loop through all the XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the BAM api directly within your looping structure?
Put in an expression shape with something like this in the loop

```
Microsoft.BizTalk.Bam.EventObservation.OrchestrationEventStream.BeginActivity("someactivity", someID);
Microsoft.BizTalk.Bam.EventObservation.OrchestrationEventStream.UpdateActivity("someactivity", someID, "someProperty", someNamespace);
Microsoft.BizTalk.Bam.EventObservation.OrchestrationEventStream.EndActivity("someactivity", someID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Typed BAM API. 
https://generatetypedbamapi.codeplex.com/

You should iniate a new BAM Activity from within the loop. 
Also, make sure you use a unique ActivityId for each XML you have in your loop, I suspect this is the problem you are experiencing now.